# How to get the IPMI address of a server?

Tags: python, ipmitool

I'm writing a Python program that collect information about the host it's running on.

Among the information to be collected is the IPMI address.

After some googling, I discovered a command line tool called `ipmitool`, but I had no idea how to make it output the IPMI address.

Comment: where is that script now? :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In one of my Ubuntu 14.04 server with IPMI, `sudo ipmitool lan print` gives an output including the IPMI management interface IP.

```
Set in Progress         : Set Complete
Auth Type Support       : NONE MD2 MD5 PASSWORD
Auth Type Enable        : Callback : MD2 MD5
                        : User     : MD2 MD5
                        : Operator : MD2 MD5
                        : Admin    : MD2 MD5
                        : OEM      :
IP Address Source       : Static Address
IP Address              : 10.0.3.80
Subnet Mask             : 255.255.0.0
MAC Address             : f0:..:..:..:..:..
SNMP Community String   : public
IP Header               : TTL=0x40 Flags=0x40 Precedence=0x00 TOS=0x10
BMC ARP Control         : ARP Responses Enabled, Gratuitous ARP Disabled
Gratituous ARP Intrvl   : 2.0 seconds
Default Gateway IP      : 10.0.0.1
Default Gateway MAC     : 00:00:00:00:00:00
Backup Gateway IP       : 0.0.0.0
Backup Gateway MAC      : 00:00:00:00:00:00
802.1q VLAN ID          : Disabled
802.1q VLAN Priority    : 0
RMCP+ Cipher Suites     : 0,1,...
Cipher Suite Priv Max   : Xa...
```